# Line of JSP code causes text to appear as hyperlink in one place but palin text in another place

Tags: java, jsp

I have this in a `jsp`:

```
<% include file="../../common.jsp %>

    <!-- engine size -->
    <c:set var="maxLength" value="4" />
    <c:set var="cssClass" value="input-text small vehicle vehicleCc vehicleSearch modelSearch" />
    <c:set var="path" value="vehicle.cc" />
    <c:set var="label" value="vehicle.cc" />
    <c:set var="explanation" value="vehicle.cc.electric" />
    <c:set var="help" value="whatsthis.cc" />
    <c:set var="helpLink" value="car.cc.link" />
    <%@ include file="../../common/fieldrows/textbox.jsp %>
   ...
```

The property `vehicle.cc.electric` has value `if electric, enter 0` When I run my application and access the engine size area through the borwser, the correct message is displayed but it appears as a hyperlink but when clicked it does not take you anywhere.

Further down the same file I have the following:

```
...
<!-- list cars -->
<c:set var="cssClass" value="largest carList" />
<c:set var="path" value="carList" />
<c:set var="label" value="vehicle.select" />
<c:set var="explanation" />
    <spring:message code="label.matching.vehicles" />
</c:set>
<%@ include file="../../common/fieldrows/listbox.jsp" %>
```

If I add `<c:set var="explanation" value="vehicle.cc.electric" />` below `<c:set var="label" value="vehicle.select" />` it appears as I wish, without looking like a hyperlink. How is this done?

**Additional info**
I noticed that `textbox.jsp` contains the following:

```
<div class="additional-info" id="informaion">
    <spring:message code="${explanation}" />
</div>
```

`listbox.jsp` is slightly different in that it does not contain the `id` field:

```
<div class="additional-info">
    <spring:message code="${explanation}" />
</div>
```

When I removed `id` from `textbox.jsp` I got `<c:set var="explanation" value="vehicle.cc.electric" />` to display as desired. I'm not sure what the purpose of `id` is though. I'm completely new to `jsp` so any info/help would be appreciated.

Comment: `<c:set>` just sets a variable to be used somewhere else (presumably in textbox.jsp and listbox.jsp) so we'd need to see how "explanation" is used on those.

Comment: Hi @Thomas just added some extra detail to my question.

Comment: "When I removed `id` I got it to display as desired" - the reason might be that some CSS or JavaScript is changing the style based on the id and if it's missing the tag won't be matched anymore. Try changing the id instead of removing it. This should have the same effect.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I'm reluctant to change `id` as I can see loads of other references to `textbox.jsp`. One option is to create a new variable. E.g `electric`. I would then have `<c:set var="electric" value="vehicle.cc.electric" />` and add this to `textbox.jsp`: `<c:if test="${!empty electric}">
    <div class="additional-info">
    <spring:message code="${electric}" />
</div>
</c:if>`. Would that be the best option?

Comment: Depends on what textbox.jsp is doing. This might be a case of bad abstraction that is biting you already. It could be an option, another might be to provide an override for the id, a third and maybe better option might be to create a copy of textbox.jsp and just use what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options to resolve this were:

1. Create a new variable. E.g `electric`. Then have `<c:set var="electric" value="vehicle.cc.electric" />` and add this to textbox.jsp:

```
<c:if test="${!empty electric}">
    <div class="additional-info">     
        <spring:message code="${electric}" /> 
    </div>
</c:if>
```

2. Provide an override for the id
3. Create a copy of textbox.jsp and just use what you need.

I went for option 1.